# How do I make sure the value of input to a function not changing when passed as pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

Pointer behaving differently in different functions.

I have created a C++ program that prints and reverses a linked list. I do not understand why the pointer behaves differently in the `pprint()` function than it does in the `reverse()` function. Please see the below code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Node{
    int data;
    Node* next;
    Node(int x):data(x),next(nullptr){};
    Node():data(0),next(nullptr){};
    Node(int x, Node* next): data(x),next(next){};
};

class LinkedList{
    public:
        void pprint(Node* head);
        Node* reverse(Node* head);
};

Node* LinkedList::reverse(Node* head){
    Node* curr = head;
    Node* next = NULL;
    Node* prev = NULL;

    while(curr!=NULL){
        next = curr->next;
        curr->next = prev;

        prev = curr; 
        curr= next; 
    }
    return prev; 
}

void LinkedList::pprint(Node* head){
    Node* curr = head;
    while(curr!=NULL){
        std::cout<<curr->data<<std::endl;
        curr =  curr->next;
    }
}

int main(){
    Node* a = new Node(); 
    Node* b = new Node();
    Node* c = new Node();

    a->data = 1;
    b->data = 2;
    c->data = 3;
    c->next = NULL; 
    b->next = c; 
    a->next = b;
    
    LinkedList LL; 
    LL.pprint(a);
    std::cout<<""<<std::endl;
    LL.pprint(LL.reverse(a));
    std::cout<<""<<std::endl;
    LL.pprint(a);
    return 0;
}
```

I am expecting the following output for this:

```
1
2
3

3
2
1

1
2
3
```

But I get the following output instead:

```
1
2
3

3
2
1

1
```

For the `pprint()` function, I am passing the `head` pointer as input, and and it is assigned to the `curr` variable. At the end of the function, the `head` value is still pointing to `a`. But in the `reverse()` function, the `a` value has become the head. How do I correct this?

Comment: It looks like you’re expecting “a” to somehow not change, but you changed all your linked list pointers in reverse(), so now a is at the end of the list. If you don’t want it to change, don’t change it. Generally this is done by making copies or similar.  But you could just reverse it again?

Comment: @Max Is it possible to create a copy of the head in reverse function, so it will not change ?

Comment: Creating the type `LinkedList` just for providing functions that work with an externally stored linked list is a poor choice; everyone reading the class name would expect the `LinkedList` to contain members storing data for 1 linked list it manages. Furthermore in C++ you should be using `nullptr` instead of `NULL`, that is unless you're working with an ancient compiler...

Comment: You would have to clone every node. This is a difference between an in-place and a copying operation.  If you use Python, list.reverse() is an in place reversal, and reversed(list) is a reversed copy of the list. But that entails copying everything as you process it.

Comment: Fwiw, it seems you've misunderstood what the class `LinkedList` should be used for. Make it keep the `head` node pointer and hide the gory `Node` details from the users of the `LinkedList`. They shouldn't have to bother about such implementation details. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/Y1hnzGKcd)

Answer (score 2):

You are correctly reversing the linked list, however after reversing you are **not updating the head pointer** to point to the new head of the reversed list.

Try this:

```
int main() {      
    Node* a = new Node(1);
    Node* b = new Node(2);
    Node* c = new Node(3);
     
    a->next = b;
    b->next = c;
    c->next = nullptr;    
    
    LinkedList LL;
    LL.pprint(a);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Reverse the list and update the head pointer
    a = LL.reverse(a);
       
    LL.pprint(a);
    std::cout << std::endl;
       
    LL.pprint(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd make a separate `head` pointer instead of reusing `a` but the solution is sound anyway.